# AngularJS - Highlight saved item

Tags: angularjs

In my AngularJS web application it is possible to create an item and save it. When the user clicks on the save button, the item is showed in the sidebar on the left.

I would like that when the item is saved, it will be highlighted for some seconds (e.g. background-color) so that the user can detect where it has been saved.

This is the button to save it.

```
<a class="pure-button pure-button-primary" ng-click="NewOrUpdateItem()">Save</a>
```

Need any other details?
any idea about this issue?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: The details that would be helpful would be the template the generates the list of saved items in the sidebar. Also, a simple Plunker with the bare minimum of code that shows you adding an item to this list would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the ngAnimate module of angular. [ngAnimate](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngAnimate)

[see here](http://jsfiddle.net/vq6gg/) for a working example

```
var module = angular.module("app", ['ngAnimate']);
....
```

Comment: thanx for your example - it is looking good for the case, an item is created. But imagine a case, where we want to show a list of items => all items are going to be "highlighted" and i don't think this side effect is wanted. Are there other ways to implement a highlight?

Answer (score 0):

I guess a proper answer will depend on your markup and list of items, if you could put a bin would be helpful. Anyway I have put this simple example together, maybe it could give you some ideas. 
When a item is saved, $scope.saved is set to true and ngClass is used to create the highlight effect, then use $timeout to unset saved. I think a directive could be a better place for this logic.

[Here is the JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/EjELezOp/1/edit)